# Got invalid syntax when entering the inputs in terminal

Tags: python, input

I wrote and ran the line

```
a,b,c =input("enter three values").split()
```

and as I typed in values 1 2 3 in the terminal, I got:

```
   File "ddd.py", line 76, in <module>
      a,b,c =input().split()
        File "<string>", line 1
            1 2 3
              ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What happened here?

Comment: The code is correct and works, the problem is somewhere else.....

Comment: Are you running Python 2 by mistake?

Comment: I have tried it and it works just fine.

Comment: no. I am running Python 3.10

Comment: It works fine, might be the problem in version of Python u are using or IDE. You should mention that

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code as the IDE.

Comment: I've reproduced the error with python 2.7 where input() is equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)). Check python version with `import sys; print(sys.version)` in your ddd.py

Comment: This is definitely an issue of using Python 2 instead of 3. please check the setup/configuration of whatever you use to run the code.

Comment: Yes, I accidentally use pyhton ddd.py to run my code. Problem solved. I'm stupid. I love you guys. <3

Comment: It is possible to reconfigure your computer so that e.g. `python` runs 3.x and `python2` runs 2.x. Nowadays, you should only have 2.x installed if you **need** it (for example, because you run an outdated operating system that came with it pre-installed, or because you use a library that is not available for 3.x and cannot find an alternative).

Answer (score -3):

I feel the inputs should be a string not integers separated with whitespace.
For example '1 2 3'

Comment: Can you be more specific? Since others said it worked fine on their computers.

Comment: I mean you should enter string like '1 2 3' in the terminal when you run the code. Try inputting '1 2 3' and drop feedback

Comment: This is only correct for Python 2.x. The problem is that OP expects to run 3.x, but is running 2.x instead.

Comment: Problem solved. I ran the wrong version and I thought I ran the right one. I love you guys. Thanks a lot!!!